# Developing for android, is there a way to cause eclipse to rebuild an app when only the source of its libraries was modified?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an app that depends on a library I wrote. When I modify the code of the library and try to run the app it happily executes the old version of the app without checking to see if the library may be outdated. I find myself adding and erasing a space character in the app source to force the rebuild.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have the following settings in Eclipse preferences:

- General -> Workspace -> Build automatically: checked
- General -> Workspace -> Refresh automatically: checked
- Run/debug -> Launching -> Build (if required) before launching: checked

Comment: I see that I didn't have Refresh automatically checked. Though making sure all these were checked didn't solve it. I even restarted eclipse to be sure.

Comment: Maybe in the Run Configuration dialog... for RCP Application there's an option "clear workspace before launch" that may help, but I don't know if it's available for Android apps.

Comment: Nope, nothing of that sort in the run configuration dialog tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Choose Project -> Clean... -> All Projects

I have found no way to do this automatically and now do it as matter of course whenever I change something I know needs refreshing.

Comment: There must be a way to automate this before each launch, no?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is stupid about files on the filesystem. Use **refresh** for it to understand that filesystem has changed.

Comment: These are modifications that are occurring in eclipse. It's as though eclipse isn't aware of the dependency.